# Где хранить загруженные фото?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Есть mern проект. На сайте есть загрузка фото,но загрузка происходит на диск.Я понимаю что хранить фотографии на диске(в корне проекта) будет не оптимально. Посмотрел что правильно будет хранить в какой-то файловой системе.Попробовал dropbox и Гугл диск,но в итоге не смог разобраться. Есть ли какие-то статьи по этому поводу? Мне нужно сделать запись,отображение в теге img ,удаление фото.
https://adxsalesarea.herokuapp.com ссылка на проект.

Comment: На любом диске всегда используется какая-нибудь файловая система... dropbox и гугл диск тут вообще ни при чём, это не файловые системы...

Comment: @andreymal Но ведь она не большая.Я смотрел на хостинге максимум 80 гб

Comment: https://cloudinary.com/pricing тариф free

Comment: @IhorStoner во-первых, посмотрите на других хостингах, существуют предложения с дисками хоть на 6 терабайт. Во-вторых, вы всегда можете собрать собственный сервер, купить в магазине дисков в нужном вам количестве и подключить их в нужном вам режиме (если деньги на покупку есть, конечно). В-третьих, неужели 80 гб это для вас мало?

Comment: @anedrymal У меня сайт объявлений очень похож на olx, на котором будет очень много фото и мне кажется что на диске эти фото хранить не оптимально. Искал хостинг,но не нашёл.

Comment: @IhorStoner amazon s3 не подходит?